# How to get the button pressed on a segmentedButton in Sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am newbie in Sencha Touch and I have a "segmentedButton" component, and I need to get the button pressed depending the user interaction in the controller.

Help please!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `getPressedButtons()` method.

Example:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var segmentedButton = Ext.create('Ext.SegmentedButton', {
            allowMultiple: true,
            items: [{
                text: 'Option 1'
            },{
                text: 'Option 2',
                pressed: true
            },{
                text: 'Option 3'
            }],
            listeners: {
                toggle: function(container, button, pressed){
                    alert("User toggled the '" + button.getText() + "' button: " + (pressed ? 'on' : 'off'));
                    console.log(container.getPressedButtons());
                }
            }
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype: 'container', padding: 10, items: [segmentedButton] });
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, with the method "getPressedButtons()" and getItemId() I can evaluate different behaviour for each button. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Inane, if the solution worked you should mark this as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @GuilhermeLopes  with your clue it was useful for me!!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the same for **Ext Classic** here is the solution.

To **get** the values use `container.getValue()`.

To **set** the values use `container.setValue()`.

Fiddle is [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26bb)